# pixel lines when copy from illustrator to photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Hi I have searched the forum for a solution of my problem but i can't seem to find one. I have made some shapes in Illustrator and added a 3D effect. It looks good in illustrator but when i try to use it in a Photoshop document some lines appear that are not there in illustrator (See photo). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to GD.SE. This is the second conflation question this week :) Is there some trend going on...

Answer (score 1):

One thing I could think of immediately would be to check the resolution of the original illustrator file and then make sure the photoshop document is set to the same resolution. Even if you want to export for web or a lower resolution later you should always be staying at the same res BEFORE exporting for the best results.

Let me know if this is wrong and I can try some stuff on my end.

There's also this handy guide: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/05/how-to-move-from-illustrator-to-photoshop-without-rasterizing-the-easy-way/

Comment: Yes, that is pixel cracking. You need to be at the same resolution.